# Using Swagger to document ASP.NET MVC endpoints (views, partialviews, etc.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger

I have an extensive MVC 5 web and I would like to internally documment its endpoints, for example what is each partial view or how it can be used.

I have done a large research and I have achieved to manage this documentation in a new ASP.Net Core Web-Api (another project) with [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle), but no luck with the MVC 5 web project.

I know that Swagger is oriented to APIs only but I'm looking forward to document my MVC endpoints somehow as Swagger does and I have been thinking if it is possible to achive this.

Is there a way to document all my endpoints using Swagger?

Comment: I think swagger only works with `APIController` (REST)

Comment: @adiga I think so... Maybe another alternative for that purpose?

Comment: What is the end goal here? You want to test your `ActionMethods` or just list them out. If it's the the latter, you could reflection and get all the methods inside every `Controller` class

Comment: (Unrelated: Now that you've mentioned, it would be a cool project to implement a `View` where you can list down `ActionMethods` of all MVC Controllers in an assembly and provide sample inputs for testing)